# I am getting an error "indexRouter is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, render

I am getting an error "indexRouter is not defined while I am trying to execute the following code. I tried removing the line but again there are other errors. Can anyone tell me why we are using this common variable router for both index.js and user.js?

This is my app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var dishRouter = require('./routes/dishRouter');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
const Dishes = require('./models/dishes');

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/conFusion';
const connect = mongoose.connect(url,{
  useMongoClient : true
});

connect.then((db) => {
  console.log('Connected correctly to the server');
},(err) => {console.log(err);});

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/index',indexRouter);
app.use('/users',usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is my index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is my users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I mean, you never defined indexRouter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong variable.

```
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/index',indexRouter); // it would be index
app.use('/users',usersRouter); // it would be users
```

Change from `indexRouter` to `index` and `userRouter` to `users`.

Comment: I don't get any error but neither the expected output in Postman